Filling GridPane with nested fxml with specific csv information
I have a fxml file i am currently working on with a GridPane with each of the cell containing anohter fxml component in following manner:
<GridPane hgap="10.0" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="543.0" prefWidth="668.0" vgap="10.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>

            <!-- Include custom component multiple times with different row and column indices -->
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
            <fx:include source="cellComponent.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
        </GridPane>

I have a csv file with columns in following manner:

"file path to a image","first number related to image", "first number related to image", "String related to the image"

There is total of 10 lines of this in csv.
The smaller fxml component is as follows:
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="#smallComponentFxml">
    <ImageView layoutY="1" />
    <Label text="1st number" fx:id="firstNumber" layoutY="150"/>
    <Label text="2nd number" fx:id="secondNumber" layoutY="150" layoutX="50"/>
    <Label text="Type" fx:id="NameOfImage" layoutY="180" layoutX="35"/>
</AnchorPane>

All the imports for the fxml and all is included.
What i want to do is, take the image using the image path and put it in the grid. same for the numbers and the name of the image. I cant seem to figure out how to do so while nesting a fxml like i have. I have been going through the documentation for fxml but no luck there.
All i want is to populate the grid with the csv imformation. i have a class to read and write the csv so there is no problem there. ive used the csv crud class else where so its functional.
Any help will be appriciated.

I suggest creating a [FXML] controller that contains a initialize() method and in that method you read the CSV file and populate the grid. By the way, I believe you are missing a layoutX in the smaller fxml component. Refer to this line: <Label text="1st number" fx:id="firstNumber" layoutY="150"/>

It doesn't make sense to me to populate the GridPane in FXML: it is too repetitive this way. Instead, populate the GridPane in Java, so you can use an appropriate loop and data structures, etc. Either way, though, you just need a reference to the controller for each of the cell components, and pass appropriate values to each such controller.

If you really want to do this in FXML (and again, I don't know why you would do that), you get a reference to each of the cell component's controllers in the main controller as described in the FXML documentation
